# Creating a vector of char pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, char

I have to make a vector that stores char pointers. Each pointer should only point to a single char like 'a' or 'b'. I don't get any compile errors, but when I run my program, it crashes. I cannot use std::string or any of its functions, they have to just be characters.

```
std::vector<char*> myVector;
myVector.reserve(10);
myVector.at(0) = new char['a'];
```

Why does the program crash? Shouldn't I be able to create new char pointers in memory as I go?

Comment: `myVector.reserve` -> `myVector.resize` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize

Comment: Also, `new char['a']` doesn't do what you think it does (you probably want `new char('a')`).

Comment: A pointer to a single char seems odd and wasteful. Why not just a vector of char?

Comment: Why not remove the headaches of character arrays and use `std::string` and `std::vector<std::string>>`?

Comment: `char chars[] = "ab"; std::vector<char*> myVector(10); myVector.at(0) = &chars[0];`?

Comment: @StephenNewell, I switched to parentheses and still the same error. The error also does not even tell me what the problem is, which adds to my problem.

Comment: I changed from reserve to resize, and that got rid of the crash, but my requirements say specifically to use reserve which is unfortunate.

Comment: Then use `resize()` after `reserve()` or use [`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) to add element(s).

Comment: `at(0)` will throw an exception, you could track the exception source in the debugger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `push_back` method of `vector` instead of using `at` when you have not pushed anything inside vector. Also, you should use `new char('a')` instead of using bracket, which has other meaning. Look at this minimal code that works just fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char*> myVector;
    myVector.push_back(new char('a'));
    std::cout << *myVector[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You won't need `static_cast<char>()` because `*myVector[0]` is already a `char`.

Comment: @MikeCAT You're right. i was playing with the code to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see line by line:

```
std::vector<char*> myVector;
```

Is there a need to keep a vector of char pointers?
What's following tells us you only want to store 1 char in there, so just use `std::string`, it'll be way easier.

```
myVector.reserve(10);
```

The reserve() methods are only used for pre-allocation, they don't actually change the size of your vector, only its capacity. For every vector: `0 <= size <= capacity`.
std::vector::at() will simply throw if you try to access something outside `[0;size[`

```
myVector.at(0) = new char['a'];
```

As we said, the `.at(0)` call will throw an exception here. But something funny will happen on the right side. Since allocating a new array is usually done with `new T[N]` where T is the type of the elements and N the size of the array, this will implicitly convert the char 'a' into an int (which is 97) and therefore allocate an array of 97 uninitialized elements.

Comment: So I adjusted to this ``` myVector.reserve(10); myVector.push_back(new char('a')); ``` The error is now gone and I can print 'a' to the screen using std::cout << *myVector.at(0); Without the * to dereference the vector element, it prints jibberish to my screen. This means that I am dealing with a pointer to a char correct?

Comment: `myVector.at(0)` is a pointer to a char, correct.